# Django project runserver failed : ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django

I failed While I was starting django project.

```
python manage.py runserver

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

And I write command line python. Then I failed While import django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

Can you hel?

Comment: Are you sure django is installed? Check it with `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you activate your virtual environment? It's basically saying you don't have django installed. Either activate your venv or `pip install django`.